# TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer. Javascript

Tags: javascript, http, npm, request

```
var formData = {
  name: 'TestDeck',
  description: 'This is a test deck for my api',
  private: false,
  shareable: false,
  ttsLanguages: [],
  blacklistedSideIndices: [],
  blacklistedQuestionTypes: [],
  gradingModes: [],
  imageAttribution: 'https://www.logogarden.com/wp-content/uploads/lg-index/Example-Logo-6.jpg',
  imageFile: fs.readFile('retext.png', 'utf8')
}

function createDeck(connection) {
  request.post({
      url: '<url>',
      formData: formData,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      },
      json: true
    }),
    function(err, resp, body) {

    }
}
```

I am getting the error: TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer.

I honestly have no idea why, need help.

Comment: `fs.readFile` is an asynchronous method, so `imageFile` most likely isn't what you think it is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several problems in the code.

1. You get `TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer` because you are trying to send boolean value `false` in form data -- HTML form does not support boolean value. In HTML, checked checkbox will send its value, while unchecked checkbox won't.

   To fix the issue, you can change `false` to `'FALSE'`(string) and parse it in server side.
2. The use of `fs.readFile('retext.png', 'utf8')` is incorrect. To attach file in the form, the right way is: `imageFile: fs.createReadStream('retext.png')`.
3. When `formData: formData` is used in `request.post(...)`, the `Content-Type` of the HTTP request would be `multipart/form-data` automatically, you don't need to define `Content-Type` header again.

   Moreover, it is incorrect to set `json: true`, which will make `Content-Type` as `application/json`. This conflict will make `request` module confused, and may cause problem in some JavaScript environment.
4. The callback function `function(err, resp, body){...}` should be part of `request.post(...)`, maybe it is a typo.

In summary, the correct code would look like:

```
var formData = {
  name: 'TestDeck',
  description: 'This is a test deck for my api',
  private: 'FALSE',
  shareable: 'FALSE',
  ttsLanguages: [],
  blacklistedSideIndices: [],
  blacklistedQuestionTypes: [],
  gradingModes: [],
  imageAttribution: 'https://www.logogarden.com/wp-content/uploads/lg-index/Example-Logo-6.jpg',
  imageFile: fs.createReadStream('retext.png')
}

function createDeck(connection) {
  request.post({
    url: '<url>',
    formData: formData
  }, function(err, resp, body) {

  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, just what I needed

Comment: you saved my day. I was appending boolean value in it. Thanks.